# Onchange is working but the value is still link to other input field

Tags: javascript, input

The `loan_pre_y1` has already a value that is linked to the `php_amount` input value. Then every time I'm changing the `loan_pre_y1` input field, the `onchange` function works but it still goes back to the value of `peso_amount`. How to fix this?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="loan_pre_y1" value="0" onchange="changeVal(this.value)"></input>
<script>
var a = get_val($('#php_amount'));
set_val($('#loan_pre_y1'), a);
</script>
```

Comment: How would anyone know what `peso_amount` or `php_amount` actually is? You need to include the applicable HTML and JavaScript as a [mcve]. Also, what exactly does `changeVal()`, `set_val()`, and `get_val()` look like code-wise? BTW `<input>` is a void element, meaning that they do not have an end tag `</input>`

Comment: That php_amount is an <input> that has also link to another <input> which contain a number, so no need to worry about that. The only problem is how to pass that php_amount to year1? get_val() and set_val() is just like this: document.getElementById('year1').value = document.getElementById('php_amount').value; Now, I've tried that code, but once I change year1's input value the value is still from the php_amount.

Comment: Yeah, it's not worth trying to visualize what you interpret without the actual code. Please read [ask] and how to post a [mcve].